# Git - rewrite commit authors when pushing to mirror repository

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

We have a git repository. There is branch `A` and there is branch `B`. They have the same contents.

New commits are added to branch `A`.

**The problem:**

Create a script that takes all new commits from branch `A`, apply them to `B` and change their commit author. The script can have the first new commit as a parameter.

Branch `A` shouldn't change.

I know how to change the commit authors using `git filter-branch` but once I do that, I won't be able to merge `A` to `B` again.

I tried to cherry pick the commits using `git cherry-pick $COMMIT..A` but that breaks on merge commits.

Is there some possibility to take the new commits and reapply them on branch them `B` automatically?

**Why we need it**

I have a project which is stored in a Git repo. Periodically, we have to also push to customer repository (about once a week), which triggers automatic builds. Unfortunately, we cannot work with customer repo directly, because it's accessible only from their intranet. That means every push to their repository is usually composed from tens of commits from different authors.

The problem is that last week their IT enabled the Verify Committer hook. This hook enforces the rule that a developer can push only their own commits. The customer is a big enterprise company and the setting won't be changed. Therefore, we will have to rewrite commit authors before pushing.

Comment: ...you need to change who committed the code so they can verify who the code was committed by?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, unfortunately. Their IT didn't think this through. They actually allow only authors with their domain email. Since we are an external company, that kind of blocks us. We considered committing into our repo with one single email but we don't want to destroy our history, therefore we have to rewrite authors before pushing to mirror. The customer manager agreed to this solution. By the way, this customer is a bank. You can imagine how flexible they are.

Comment: No matter which method you take to rewrite the commits, `A` should not be merged to `B`. Once they are merged, the commits with original authors are part of `B` and won't pass the verification. As you are forging authors, it's not necessary to keep `B` in the graph exactly the same with `A`. It's okay as long as they have the same files. If any defect is found in `B`, you can always find out who is responsible for it in `A`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I know I don't have to merge them, I am speaking about the way how to get new commits from A to B. The only way I see now is to always delete B, create B from A and rewrite committers for all commits until the common ancestor. If the script is always the same, the resulting commits will also be the same. However, rewriting thousands of commits will be slow. I am currently trying some magic with `git replace` and `git rebase` to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there any chance that commits will be made in B that you also need to get back into A? Otherwise, can you make A a repository with always one commit that includes all the code at the tip of B's master branch? That would be a lot simpler but it requires force pushing each update onto their repository.

Comment: No commits will be made on B but obviously I don't have rights to force push.

Comment: Ah, so that's the problem with recreating B from scratch every time? The commits you have already pushed need to remain exactly the same so that the new update doesn't need a force push?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn If the branch is always created the same way, the result will be the same. Therefore I could recreate it from scratch and wouldn't need a force push. However, recreating it would take signicant time and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: When you rebase, the time and author that did the rebase is in the new commit. So even though the method will be the same, the commits will be different ones.